# How To Pull Out Array Data From Model To Controller In Php JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I was trying to pull out data from my `model`, and its results are in array. I tried to pass the return object in  to my `controller`, and echo the result in `JSON`, but it seems it cannot receive the object.

I making another `php` file not in `MC` pattern. And it work.

Here's my code for getting the `objects` (This one works - sequential approach):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){

     require('dbConnect.php');

     $SQLi_ORG_FEEDS = "SELECT  organizationName,
                                organizationDescription,
                                organizationCategory,
                                organizationCurrentMembers,
                                organizationMaxMembersNo,
                                organizationType,
                                organizationLogo,
                                organizationLogoPath 
                        FROM org_information";

     $query = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$SQLi_ORG_FEEDS) or die("Error".mysqli_error($dbConnect));

     $checkRow = mysqli_num_rows($query);

     $response = array();

     if($checkRow > 0){
         while ($getRecord = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $response[] = $getRecord;

         }                
            echo json_encode($response);
     }
     else {
            $response['failed'] = 'failed';
            echo json_encode($response);
     }
```

Result in `POSTMAN`

[image: sample]

This method is from my `model` :

```
 public function getAllOrgRegistered(){

            //STATEMENT
                $sql_show_org = "SELECT  organizationName,
                                         organizationDescription,
                                         organizationCategory,
                                         organizationCurrentMembers,
                                         organizationMaxMembersNo,
                                         organizationType,
                                         organizationLogo,
                                         organizationLogoPath 
                                 FROM    org_information";

            //EXECUTE
                $result       = mysqli_query($this->db->connect,$sql_show_org) or die(mysqli_error($this->db->connect));
                $checkResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                 $response = array();
            //CHECK FOR RESULTS
                if ($checkResults > 0) {
                    while ($getRecord = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $response[] = $getRecord;
                    }

                    return $response;
                }else{
                    return FALSE;
                }

        }
```

I echo the `json` object. **How do I catch this response from my `model` to my `controller` ?**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){

    //INCLUDE CLASS
         require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/yayongeppn/OOP/models/orgCreateOrganization.php');

    //NEW INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT
        $orgCreate = new orgCreateOrganization();

    //TAG
        $tag = $_POST['tag'];

        if($tag == 'org'){


                    $response = array();

                    $result = $orgCreate->getAllOrgRegistered();
                        if ($result != FALSE) {

                            //  while ($getRecord = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            //          $response[] = $getRecord;
                            //  }



                            echo json_encode($result);

                        }else{
                            $response['error'] = "Failed to fetch data.";
                            echo json_encode($response);
                        }

        }

    }//END SERVER
```

I really need your help.

Comment: Read up on [return](http://php.net/return) which you should be using in your model instead of `echo`. You probably don't want to json_encode in the model at all either since you do that later in the controller. You also don't seem to be taking account of your model's function returning multiple results (i.e. a multi-dimensional array).

Comment: I changed it to `return $response` . Is my `controller` right when getting the data's?

Comment: No it's not quite right. See my updated comment.

Comment: Can you help me with this one, I'm really poor at `multi-dimen arrays` : (

Comment: If you're just after the same output you had before, can you not just `echo json_encode($result);` in your controller instead of all your `$response` stuff?

Comment: I've updated my post. Yes, I'm after with the same output. Will It automatically return it in - `Arrays` ?

Comment: Yes, json_encode will encode the entire thing.

Comment: Sir Jon, Thank you. It's now working. : )